# How can I find out what jQuery functions I use in my scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grep

I'm attempting to audit my code so that I can find out what jQuery functions I use and how many of them I use. The goal is to remove jQuery and alias its functions with native browser implementations to save on page weight.

Simply put I want to match any jQuery function: `$("#whatever").methodname(...`

I have tried a basic regular expression to find the times where I use a jQuery selector, which looks a bit like this:

```
grep -r \$\([\"\'].+[\"\']\)\. jscript/*.js
```

However, this isn't working very well, and I also want it to match against function names and count them up for me. Can you help?

Comment: What is the exactly input you are looking for?

Comment: How about replacing the `$` variable with a proxy function of your own that (i) logs (ii) calls jQuery

Comment: I'm looking to match $("#xxx").methodname and count up the instances of that methodname

Comment: @SalmanA I'm looking to audit code when it isn't running. Knowledge of the whole system should not be a requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do that with simple regex lookups.

You need a tool that understands JavaScript, like [grasp](http://graspjs.com).

With grasp installed, you could do `grasp '#$' file.js` to find the references to the `$` variable.

Comment: I've found that this command works best: grasp '$(__).__' -e *.js - it doesn't do the counting, but it's close enough. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! You could try to do the counting using the `-o` option for grasp and adding a sed filter to get only the function names: `grasp '$(__).__' -e -o *.js | sed 's/.*[.]//' | uniq -c`. This fails for some code for the same reasons that grep, but maybe it can help you get an estimate.